# Firebase Hosting Image URL best practice

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have just uploaded some images to firebase storage. I have a React App which I am using Google Firestore to fetch data (snapshot). I have a field imageURL which is a string in firestore and would like to paste this image url from storage.
Do I use  the link pictured in the attached graphic? it has the url `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/.....` or there is another link which is not viewable which starts with `gs://domain.com...` ?

[image]

Comment: *"I want to call an image url link from API"* - what exactly does that mean?  Please edit the question to make your destination clear.

Comment: Apologies I have updated the answer hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead store the path to the image in your bucket (not the URL), then use Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage and use [getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#get-downloadurl) to fetch a URL programmatically in your app, [as shown in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).

Comment: Hmm ok, I am basically mapping through JSON objects and displaying them, not really wanting to make it more complicated than it needs to be. My portfolio items consist of a number of fields `[{ title:"...", description: "...", imageURL: "..." }, {}] ` and so on. Does it have to be done this way? Is it more secure this way ?

Comment: You will probably not want to assume that the URL has already been created as you see in the dashboard. Depending on how you uploaded the file, it might not exist yet.  It also might be deleted in the future.  If you just want static file hosting, use Firebase Hosting instead. It will be easier.

Comment: I will point out that Firebase Storage is built on top of Cloud Storage, so if you want to learn how to configure your bucket for public access you might have some other options, but that is a whole other thing to learn.